# Dynamic button click event in webkit browser using C#

Tags: c#, webkit

I have Created a dynamic button in Webkit browser in c# code.
I want to perform button click event for the dyanmic button.
How can I perform button click event handler?

I generated the button using documenttext in webkitbrowser:
`mBrowser.DocumentText =
              "<html><head><script>" +
              "function test(message) { alert(message); }" +
              "</script></head><body><button " +
              "onclick=\"window.external.Test('called from script code')\">" +
              "call client code from script code</button>" +
              "</body></html>";`

Now the Test function does not works.

Please provide me an example which will be helpfull for me.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `window.external.test('called from script code')` instead of `window.external.Test('called from script code')`?

Comment: Hi, Ashwin! Please check [my question about WebKit-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576038/html-ui-using-webkit). I'm sure you can suggest something. Regards!